# connect to mssql with password that containts @

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am using nodes mssql module in order to connect to mssql database.  However my password contains @ and the pattern to the connection is

```
mssql://username:password@localhost/database
```

It throws connection error. I assume it is because it sees @ so content after it it takes as localhost and so on.

Is there a way how to connect there with password that contains @?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

certain symbols must be enclosed by double quotation marks (") or square brackets ([ ]).

Use these delimiters in Transact-SQL statements when the SQL Server login, user, role, or password has the following characteristics:

1.Contains or starts with a space character.
2. Starts with the $ or @ character.